# An exception raised during rendering

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I have updated my sdk to 6.0(23) and now I am implementing navigation drawer and getting this error. I have changed theme also but that didn't helped me.

I restarted Eclipse again and am still getting the same error. I tried Build Path also and checked android and android dependency that also didn't solve my problem. I don't have much experience in android. Are there any solution?

```
Exception raised during rendering:
Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class <unknown> 
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
(Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Comment: You'll want to make sure that all of the support libraries are up to date from the SDK manager. Also, you should see if your build tools is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Check the android version and support library checkbox, it can solve your problem.